# Is db_set_active a global or local setting?

Tags: 7, views, database

I need to run a new query on another database.

I configured the **settings.php**

```
 $databases = array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'default' => 
        array (
          'database' => 'db_name',
          'username' => 'db_usr',
          'password' => '',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'port' => '',
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'prefix' => '',
        ),
      ),
      'slave' => 
      array (
        'default' => 
        array (
          'database' => 'db_name',
          'username' => 'db_usr',
          'password' => '',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'port' => '',
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'prefix' => '',
        ),
      ),
    );
```

and this is my custom function:

```
    function myModule_test()
{

    db_set_active('slave');

    sleep(90);

    $view = views_get_view('test_view');
    $view->set_display('page');
    $view->pre_execute();
    $view->execute();

    print $view->render();
    db_set_active();

    }
```

the query is performed on the second database, what I do not understand is if the database change is **local or global**, because during the `sleep (90)` I tried to insert a new 'article' content and it has been inserted into the 'default' database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a per-request global setting. `db_set_active` calls:

```
Database::setActiveConnection($key);
```

Which sets the static `$activeKey` property of the [`Database`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/class/Database/7.x) class.

[`Database::getConnection()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/Database%3A%3AgetConnection/7.x), which is where the connection for all queries comes from, then uses that same static `$activeKey`.

So once you've used `db_set_active`, all queries in that request will use the new connection until changed again.

It doesn't persist across multiple requests.

Comment: I'm sorry, an explanation: why was the inclusion of a new content done in the main database?

Comment: You haven’t provided any details so I can only guess, but given that `sleep` blocks the request, if you managed to insert content while it wa sleeping, that would’ve been in a separate request. Presumably you didn’t change the connection from default for that separate request